# Table not found HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate

Estava fazendo alguns testes com o hibernate usando classes abstratas para criar um tipo de herança e gerar meu DB a partir das classes, mas obtive um problema ao tentar persistir.

O caso é, tenho uma classe abstrata funcionário e outra dentista e atendente quando peço para o hibernate gerar o banco ele mostra o *erro de table not* found, mas ainda sim cria o banco corretamente, Quanto tento persistir tenho o mesmo erro acompanhado de:

> Hibernate: select tbl.next_val from hibernate_sequences tbl where
>   tbl.sequence_name=? for update of tbl Hibernate: update
>   hibernate_sequences set next_val=?  where next_val=? and
>   sequence_name=? Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')

Qual é o problema com o código, estarei deixando as classes aqui.

Classe funcionario:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Funcionario implements Serializable, EntidadeBase {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable=false,length=100)
private String nome;

@Column(nullable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dtNascimento;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Double salario;

@Column(nullable=false,length=14,unique=true)
private String cpf;

@Column(nullable=false,length=3)
private String sexo;

@Column(nullable=false,length=13)
private String telefone;

@Column(nullable=false,length=15,unique=true)
private String celular;

@Column(nullable=false,unique=true,length=100)
private String email;

@Column(nullable=false,unique=true,length=11)
private String tituloEleitor;

@Column(nullable=false,length=10,unique=true)
private int Num_Serie_CTPS;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
private Endereco endereco;

//Construtor
public Funcionario(){
    this.endereco = new Endereco();
}
```

Classe dentista:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_dentista")
public class Dentista extends Funcionario implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(unique=true,nullable=false,length=6)
private String cro;

@Column(nullable=false,length=50)
private String especialidade;

//getters e setters
public String getCro() {
    return cro;
}

public void setCro(String cro) {
    this.cro = cro;
}

public String getEspecialidade() {
    return especialidade;
}

public void setEspecialidade(String especialidade) {
    this.especialidade = especialidade;
}

//construtor
public Dentista(){

}
```

Classe atendente:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_atendente")
public class Atendente extends Funcionario implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Atendente(){

}

//Não tem nada que não seja o que já tem em funcionario!
}
```